# Regularity up to the boundary of solutions of the heat equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity, heat-equation, semigroups-of-operators

Given the heat problem:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t)=\Delta u(x,t)  & \forall (x,t)\in \Omega\times(0,T) \\
u(x,0)=u_0(x)  & \forall x\in\Omega \\
u(x,t)=0 & \forall x\in\partial\Omega, t>0
\end{cases}.$$
if $\Omega$ is smooth enough (not necessarily bounded) and $u_0\in L^2(\Omega)$, one can assure  that we have solutions $u\in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega}\times(0,T))$ (the initial data is reached in the sense that $u(t)\to u_0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ when $t\to 0$.) This can be proved, for example, with Semigroup Theory: $(-\Delta,H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega))$ generates a semigroup in $L^2(\Omega)$ ([Davies] Sections 1.3, 1.4) which is analytic. Therefore, $u(t)\in D((-\Delta)^{k})$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Now, using higher regularity results (see for example Evans Section 6.3 Theorem 5) one can prove that $D((-\Delta)^k)\subset H^{2k}(\Omega)$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $u(t)\in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ for every $t>0$.
However, one can consider a more general problem:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t)=\Delta u(x,t)  & \forall (x,t)\in \Omega\times(0,T) \\
u(x,0)=u_0(x)  & \forall x\in\Omega \\
Bu(x,t)=0 \forall & x\in\partial\Omega, t>0
\end{cases}.$$
where $Bu$ corresponds to Dirichlet ($Bu=u$), Neumann ($Bu=\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$) or Robin ($Bu=\alpha\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}+\beta u$) and $u_0\in L^p(\Omega)$ where $1\leq p \leq \infty$. I think that, if $\partial\Omega$ and the cofficients of $B$ are smooth, it is well-known that $u\in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega}\times(0,T))$. However, I do not find any good reference for this.

In this general case, I know that $-\Delta$ (with an adequate domain, see [Denk]) generates a semigroup in $L^p(\Omega)$ (See for example [Davies]). However, it is not analytic if $p=1,\infty$. Furthermore, there are regularity results in the $L^p$ framework (See [GT] Theorem 9.19. In this case higher regularity in $L^p$ is left as an exercise in the homogeneous Dirichlet case (I think the authors forgot to mention that it is for Dirichlet)). There are also regularity results for the Poisson problem with other boundary conditions (See for example [Mikhailov] P.217 Theorem 4, which is stated for Dirichlet and Neumann, and the footnote includes Robin).

However, I could not deduce from all these result the fact that $u\in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega}\times(0,T)$ in the general case (that is, when $u_0\in L^p(\Omega)$ and for Dirichlet, Robin or Neumann B.C.) but just for some particular cases as $1<p<\infty$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions or $p=2$ with any boundary condition. I feel there may be an easier way to do this. Do you know how? Or, do you know any **reference** for this?

---

References:

[Evans] [Partial differential equations](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exushijie/pdf/textbooks/pde-evans.pdf). Evans, L. C. (2022).

[Davies] [Heat Kernels and Spectral Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/heat-kernels-and-spectral-theory/39DC7EE2A5DCCE9DEF581D2F52A73E1F). E. B. Davies.

[Denk] [New thoughts on old results of RT Seeley](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-003-0493-y). R Denk, G Dore, M Hieber, J Prüss, A Venni.

[GT] [Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61798-0). D Gilbarg, NS Trudinger.

[Mikhailov] [Partial Differential Equations](https://archive.org/details/MikhailovPartialDifferentialEquations). V.P. Mikhailov.

Comment: Why it is not analytic for $p=1, \infty$?

Comment: I don't quite follow; if you are interested in regularity for $t > 0$, the regularity of the initial condition is completely irrelevant to the question of higher regularity. You can prove estimates like $\|u(t, \cdot)\|_{X(\Omega)} \leq \|u\|_{Y([0, 1]\times\Omega)} $ where $Y$ is e.g. $L^2$ or the energy space or $L^\infty$ or whatever you like, and $X$ is $C^k$ or whatever higher-regularity space you prefer. You then might want to have a global estimate for the $Y$ norm in terms of $u_0$, but this is separate from the question of the $Y$ to $X$ estimate.

Comment: If you are asking for the $Y$ to $X$ part, you can use elliptic estimates (after decomposing into a basis of eigenfunctions, or roughly equivalently with semigroup language). One reference for the non-Dirichlet problems is the book by Gary Lieberman on oblique derivative problems, which is kind of like the Gilbarg-Trudinger for them. If you are asking for the global $u_0$ to $Y$ part, this will usually come from heat kernel estimates and your reference of Davies is where I would look (perhaps some of the others here know of good references for the oblique derivative problem in particular).

Comment: @user378654 Thank you for your answer. Maybe I did not explained myself well. I am interested in estimating the X norm that you describe. I did not know I could obtain $C^\infty$ regularity up to the boundary of $u(t)$ from the fact that $u\in L^2([0,1]\times\Omega)$. I will check the reference you gave me.
However, my problem is to obtain estimates of $Y$ and this depends on the regularity of $u_0$. For example, if $u_0\in L^\infty$ then $u\notin L^2([0,1]\times\Omega)$ in general. I will try with heat kernel estimates as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Umm I was looking for a reference because I thought It was not analytic in those cases, but I could not find it. Maybe it is, but at least [Davies] do not cover this case (However Davies works in a more general setting, and gives a counterexample for $p=1$ with another operator I think).

Comment: Maybe you find what your are looking for in "R-boundedness, Fourier multipliers and problems of elliptic and parabolic type" by Dek, Hieber, Pruss. Everything is vector-valued but in the language of semigroup theory.